# SQL Query: Join causes triplicate result

Tags: mysql, sql

**Program**  SQL using mySQL (phpMyAdmin) & MySQL Workbench
**Skill level**  None to speak of
**Note** The /*PREFIX*/ came with the SQL I contracted to be written 18 months ago.

Hi there,
I am trying to retrieve the Country, CountryID & State from my SQL database.
Unfortunately It is required that a second join be used as Country is in (orders T5); CountryID & State in (address_book T7).

From what I have read it could be too many joins?  (I'm a little confused).

The Join causing the issue (I have tried: Inner, Left, Right joins):

```
left Join /*PREFIX*/address_book T7 On (T7.customers_id = T5.customers_id)
```

The full FROM clause:

```
From /*PREFIX*/products T1
    Left Join /*PREFIX*/orders_products T2 On (T1.products_id = T2.products_id)
    Inner Join /*PREFIX*/orders T5 On (T5.orders_id = T2.orders_id)
    Inner Join /*PREFIX*/products_description T3 On (T1.products_id = T3.products_id)
    Inner Join /*PREFIX*/customers T6 On (T5.customers_id = T6.customers_id)
    **left Join /*PREFIX*/address_book T7 On (T7.customers_id = T5.customers_id)**
    Left Join /*PREFIX*/paypal P1 On (P1.order_id = T5.orders_id)
    Left Join /*PREFIX*/manufacturers T4 On (T1.manufacturers_id = T4.manufacturers_id)
    Where (T5.date_purchased >= 20120101) 
    And (T5.date_purchased <= 20140227) 
    And T5.orders_status = 1
```

The query contains all store order information

```
Select
-- Other store Query --

-- Customer Information --
    T5.customers_id As CID,
    T6.customers_firstname As CFirst,
    T6.customers_lastname As CLast,
    T5.customers_name As CName,
    T5.customers_email_address As CEmail,
    T5.customers_country As CCountry,

    -- Following 2 lines from the 'FROM'
    T7.entry_country_id As CCountryID,
    T7.entry_state As CState,
```

I know it could do with some tidying, but I am not much more than a beginner at SQL, just enough to troubleshoot little bits of code, and paste it back together.

Using Copy/Create Statement

```
CREATE TABLE `address_book` (
  `address_book_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `entry_gender` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `entry_company` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `entry_lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `entry_street_address` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `entry_suburb` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `entry_city` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `entry_state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_country_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `entry_zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`address_book_id`),
  KEY `idx_address_book_customers_id_zen` (`customers_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2917 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Propably customers can have multiple addresses and that causes result multiplication. You should try and read about how LEFT JOIN works.

Comment: you did not take into account 1 to many relations between tables. what if one customer has multiple address? which address country information are you going to use? do you have any preference or a default address? we could provide you with a way to reduce your result to distinct rows with group by but is that really what you need? get a random country from user's address and ignore others?

Comment: Show us the definition of the `address_book` table including any keys and/or relationships.

Comment: @Ziouas I've checked the orders that duplicate, at least 1 does have a different Customer & Billing Address.  So, the next thing is to find then the columns that information is located in the tables.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok, then I'd make that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of rows returned is not a matter of "too many" joins, per se, it's really a matter of the cardinality of the rows in the tables that are being joined.

For example, if a `customer` can have zero one or more `delivery`, then a query that does a join between `customer` and `delivery` is going to return "duplicate" customer, for any customer that has more than one delivery.

From what you've explained, it sounds as if a customer can (and does) have more than one associated row in address_book, and a query of just `address_book` on that particular customers_id will return three rows.

The behavior you observe is entirely expected.

There's basically two approaches to avoiding "duplicates" being returned. One is to use a the DISTINCT keyword or a GROUP BY clause to specify that rows be collapsed. The other general approach is to filter rows from the multi table so that the duplicates don't get generated, either using an inline view, or in some cases, a correlated subquery in the SELECT list.

For example, you could replace the JOIN to address book with a join to an inline view, to get a single address_book_id for each customers_id, and then join that to the address_book table to retrieve the other columns from the row with that id.

That is, replace this:

```
left Join /*PREFIX*/address_book T7 On (T7.customers_id = T5.customers_id)
```

with something like this:

```
LEFT 
JOIN ( SELECT T9.customers_id
            , MAX(T9.address_book_id) AS max_address_book_id
         FROM /*PREFIX*/address_book T9
        GROUP BY T9.customers_id
     ) T8
  ON T8.customers_id = T6.customers_id
LEFT
JOIN /*PREFIX*/address_book T7
  ON T7.customers_id = T8.customers_id
 AND T7.address_book_id = T8.max_address_book_id
```

Comment: thank you, that worked. I don't know how, but it did. It is now picking up the `Billing Address` and instead of 3 rows, I now have 1 per order where multiple addresses were used.

Comment: @MrsAdmin: While a customer can have multiple entries in address_book, perhaps in your model, an `order` can be related to only one address. Is there a foreign key to `address_book` in the `order` table? Such that you could include a join predicate between those two tables, so that you would get the address for an order, rather than getting just one of the addresses associated with a customer. If that's the case, you would probably prefer that, getting the address associated with the order, over just getting "some one" address for the customer.

Answer (score 2):

Propably customers can have multiple addresses and that causes result multiplication. You should try and read about how LEFT JOIN works